# Adding to Array where Key equals Variable

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I always have trouble wrapping my head around these foreach array things, and SO has been an incredibly value resource in getting me there, so I hope you guys can help with this one.

```
public function progress_bar()
{

    $items = array(
        array(
            'step-name' => 'Setup',
            'url' => '/projects/new/setup/',
        ),
        array(
            'step-name' => 'Artwork',
            'url' => '/projects/new/artwork/',
        ),
        array(
            'step-name' => 'Review',
            'url' => '/projects/new/review/',
        ),
        array(
            'step-name' => 'Shipping',
            'url' => '/projects/new/shipping-info/',
        ),
        array(
            'step-name' => 'Billing',
            'url' => '/projects/new/billing/',
        ),
        array(
            'step-name' => 'Receipt',
            'url' => '/projects/new/receipt/',
        ),
    );

    // Status can be active, editing, or complete.

    foreach ($this->progress as $step => $status)
    {
        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            $item['step-name'] == ucfirst($step) ? $item['status'] = $status : '';
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

`$this->progress` contains an array of statuses `('setup' => 'active', 'artwork' => 'editing')`

I want to add to the `$items` array the status of each matching item in `$this->progress`

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'step-name' => 'Setup',
        'url' => '/projects/new/setup',
        'status' => 'active',
    ),
    etc...
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is that you are trying to add an array element to $items, but what you're actually doing is adding the element to a temporary variable ($item), which does not reference the original $items variable.

I'd suggest approaching it like this:

```
foreach ($this->progress as $step => $status)
{
    // Having the $key here allows us to reference the
    // original $items variable.
    foreach ($items as $key => $item)
    {
        if ($item['step-name'] == ucfirst($step) )
        {
            $items[$key]['status'] = $status;
        }
    }
}

return $items;
```

Comment: Yes, you did understand correctly, and yes I recognized it was temporary but didn't know how to make it permanent, and yes, you rule and saved the day!!

Comment: Excellent on all fronts then!

Answer (score 0):

Are you locked into using an array to store $items?  If so, you're going to be stuck doing a nested loop ("For each element in $this->progress, check each element in $items.  If match, update $items" or something like that).  If you have some flexibility, I would use a hash for $items (associative array in php-speak), where the index is the step name.  So $items['Setup'] would contain 'url' => ... and 'status' => ... etc.  Does that make sense?  Then your algorithm breaks down to "For each element in $this->progress, get the element in $items by name ($items[$step_name]) and update it's info."

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you have the $items array keyed and do it like this. Stops you from having the nested loops.

```
public function progress_bar()
{

    $items = array(
        'Setup' => array(
                'url' => '/projects/new/setup/',
               ),
        'Artwork' => array(
                    'url' => '/projects/new/artwork/',
                ),
        'Review' => array(
                    'url' => '/projects/new/review/',
                ),
        'Shipping' => array(
                    'url' => '/projects/new/shipping-info/',
                ),
        'Billing' => array(
                    'url' => '/projects/new/billing/',
                ),
        'Receipt' => array(
                    'url' => '/projects/new/receipt/',
                )
    );

    // Status can be active, editing, or complete.

    foreach ($this->progress as $step => $status)
    {
        $item[ucfirst($step)]['status'] = $status;
    }

    return $items;
}
```